# mySQL query comparing rows and columns

Tags: mysql

I have a database of user answers from a quiz which contains 8 questions. Q1 - Q8 all are their own columns, I'd like to compare all the rows and get a number back for everyone who answered the same for at least 5 questions.

[image]

so here, rows 5 and 6 would count as 2. Basically I'm trying to get a number for everyone who answered at least 5 questions the same. Is this possible with a mySQL query?

EDIT:

[image]

Here the user enters D B D A B C D B, matching with 2 similarly answered quizzes. The query here would return a count of 2.

Comment: 5 questions the same relative to what benchmark? Is this going to be aggregated on a per-user basis?

Comment: Yes this is a per user basis, I assume the benchmark would mean what the user's answers were. So if I answered B A A A A A C A this would return a 2 since there's already two rows in the database with 5 answers similar.

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to get as a result here, since both your explanations are the same and bear no relation to your data. Can you please edit your question and demonstrate how you calculate the results you describe in your last comment? I don't see any way `3` would be the result.

Comment: In your edited post - if you answer BAAAAAAA, wouldn't it return 2 as both rows 5 and 6 share at least 5 answers in common with you?

Comment: The new image hopefully will clear up the question a bit more. But yes it would return 2, the row just needs 5 of the same answers as the current user's to count as a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we test using just your single line of D B D A B C D B we can use the following example:

```
SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE  ((CASE WHEN q1 = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN q2 = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN q3 = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +         
(CASE WHEN q4 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN q5 = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN q6 = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN q7 = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +         
(CASE WHEN q8 = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 5;
```

However, if we then want to go a step further and test each answer against the other answers in the table we can use the following statement:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(answer_sub.idanswers) FROM `answers` answer_sub     
WHERE ((CASE WHEN answer_sub.q1 = a.q1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q2 = a.q2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q3 = a.q3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q4 = a.q4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q5 = a.q5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q6 = a.q6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q7 = a.q7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q8 = a.q8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 5     
AND answer_sub.idanswers <> a.idanswers) as matching    
FROM `answers` a    
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(answer_sub.idanswers) FROM `answers` answer_sub     
WHERE ((CASE WHEN answer_sub.q1 = a.q1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q2 = a.q2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q3 = a.q3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q4 = a.q4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q5 = a.q5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q6 = a.q6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q7 = a.q7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +     
(CASE WHEN answer_sub.q8 = a.q8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 5     
AND answer_sub.idanswers <> a.idanswers) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `FALSE` is `0` and `TRUE` is `1` in MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM quiz
WHERE ( (q1=@q1) + (q2=@q2) + (q3=@q3) + (q4=@q4)
      + (q5=@q5) + (q6=@q6) + (q7=@q7) + (q8=@q8) 
      ) >= 5
```